# Firebase Returning Single Field of Single Result

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

I am somewhat new to firebase.

I have been using observables like this

```
 getClients()
  {
    return this.firestore.collection('Clients').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

However, I want to just return a string value of a field, so I can go from an Id to a looked up friendly name.

I tried with this,

```
  getClientById(clientID: string)
  {
    return this.firestore.collection('Clients').doc(clientID).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

I also, tried calling .get(),
However, I have not seen a way to just return the field.

This must be simple.
Basically, I use ngFor to show all the clinics, however, I use the field 'clientId' instead of copying the clientName (in case they change the name).
So, in the ngFor I have 'aClinic.ClientId',
however, I want to call a function in my service, which will take a ClientId, look it up from the Client table, and return the ClientName associated.

Any Thoughts?
Thank-you
Chris

Answer (score 2):

For web and mobile applications, Firestore doesn't provide a way to query for only specific individual document fields.  You will always get the entire contents of any documents matched by a query.  There is no way to filter out unwanted fields.  If you are trying to save bandwidth, you should consider splitting a document into multiple documents so you get only what you want.

If you are writing backend code, you could use [select()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#select) (on nodejs for example) to choose fields, but this isn't available on web and mobile clients.

Comment: it isnt so much about performance.
Most of the code I have followed the data denormalization. That is how I handled the services offered... but, now I want each clinic belonging to a client, so I was going to use the id from the other table and look it up (my mind must be thinking ms sql).... I can denormalize the data.... I just would have to cascade updates if the client names changed